# Firebase data deleted upon page refresh in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been stumped on a work around for this problem for a while now and was hoping someone could help.

I am currently working on a React UI that sends info to the backend Firebase for a budgeting app.
When the page first loads, I pull in the data using this:

```
const [incomeSources, setIncomeSources] = React.useState([]);

/////////////////////////////////
// PULL IN DATA FROM FIREBASE //
///////////////////////////////

  async function getData() {
    const doc = await getDoc(userCollectionRef);

    const incomesData = doc.data().incomeSources;
    // const expensesData = doc.data().expenses;
    // const savingsData = doc.data().savingsAllocation;

    // SET STATES //
    if (incomesData.length > 0) {
      setIncomeSources(incomesData);
    }

  }
```

then when I want to add a new object to the state array I use a input and button. The issue I currently have is that I have it set up like this:

```
async function updateFirebaseDocs(userID, stateName, state) {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", userID);
  try {
      await setDoc(userRef, { [stateName]: state }, { merge: true });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error("error adding document", err);
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  updateFirebaseDocs(userID, 'incomeSources', incomeSources)
},[incomeSources])
```

[image: It works and uploads fine]

this works so long as I don't refresh the page, because upon page refresh, incomeSources defaults back to an empty array on render. Causing firebase docs to become an empty array again which deletes firestore data.

I can't for the life of me figure out the workaround even though I know its probably right in front of me. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Brief summary: I am able to pull in data from backend and display it, but I need a way to keep the backend database up to date with changes made in the Frontend. And upon refreshing the page, I need the data to persist so that the backend doesn't get reset.

Please advise if more information is needed. First time posting.

I have tried using the above method using useEffects dependency, I have also tried using localstorage to work around this but also don't can't think of a way of implementing it. I feel I am tiptoeing around the solution.

Comment: Hey @enticedcode why your refresh the page?!!.. just a question...

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Aside from that: it sounds like your `updateFirebaseDocs` isn't storing the data in Firestore then. Without seeing the code for that function, it's hard to say why that is. --- I recommend also checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for the tips! I went ahead and updated with the snippet that uploads to Firestore. It does work on updating the backend, its just refreshing the page renders an empty array, and the useEffect immediately overwrites. I haven't been able to think of a workaround for this, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi @VarunKaklia, I know its not necessary to refresh the page but in case it is refreshed I want my data to persist but still get the latest changes made frontend. For example if I already have an array saved on the backend and I refresh, it gets overwritten by my initial state declaration of an empty array.